# Minimum norm matrix to stablize a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, control-theory

Suppose all of the eigenvalues of $A$ locate strictly on the right half plane. $(A,B)$ is controllable, $H$ is symmetric and strictly positive definite.

I wonder is there a optimal solution $H^*$ for the following problem:

$\inf \|H\|_2$

$s.t. A-BB^TH $ is stable, i.e. all of its eigenvalues are strictly located on the left half plane.

Comment: Do you mean stable or asymptotically stable? Do you mean if the minimizer exist and not just an infimizer?

Comment: I did mean asymptotically stable, i.e. the eigenvalues of A-BB^TH all strictly locate on the left half plane. About minimizer and infimizer, I did mean the minimizer, not just an infimizer. But infimizer is acceptable.

Comment: Well, minimizer is probably out of the question, as the feasible set is open. So what you actually ask about is a procedure to compute a solution to your problem then, not whether there is a solution to the problem. It appears to have close resemblance with an LQ solution, where the optimal feedback is -B^TH where H is the inverse Lyapunov cost